# Why must subbundle be an embedded submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In John Lee's smooth manifold, pg 264, or [199 in this version](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=w4bhBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=smooth%20subbundle&source=bl&ots=FokNeRVLPB&sig=Jk1zGzA_Y8iDu6GjWSovnOmTDAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj277LM5trdAhXrLMAKHWs4AcQQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=smooth%20subbundle&f=false), he defines

> Let $\pi:E \rightarrow M$ be a vector smooth bundle. A subbundle $\pi|_D:D \rightarrow M$ is called a **smooth subbundle** if it is smooth vector bundle and an **embedded submanifold** with or without boundary.

---

Being **embedded** in Lee's definition has two conditions:

1. It is a topological embedding.
2. It is a smooth immersion. That is $di_p :T_pD \rightarrow T_pE$ is injective for all $p \in D$.

---

$D$ can be given  subspace topology. 1. is then satisfied.

But why do we require in the definition that it is a **smooth immersion?**  Is this condition additonal? Or could actually be deduced?

Comment: note that $i$ maps $D$ into $E$, not into $M$. (this is not an attempt to answer your question, but it may be a hint to a misconception you may have)

Comment: If it's not an embedding, then your trivialization maps may not restrict to homeomorphisms, since $D$ doesn't necessarily inherit the subspace topology of $E$.  It may be still true that $D\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle, but it's not a subbundle of $E\to M$.

Comment: ＠Thomas, thaanks that was a typo. @Matt is it possible that: D is a subbundle , D has subspace topology, but $D \rightarrow E$ is not an embedding? My problem is that I feel the condition of smooth immersion is "forced", if you get what I mean, but could not formalize it.

Comment: @CL I don't understand what you're asking.  If you don't have an immersion, then you can't think of $T_pD$ as a subspace of $T_pE$.  So $D\subset E$, but the smooth structures aren't compatible in a nice way.  This defeats the purpose of working in the smooth category.  You could just have $D$ is a topological embedding into $E$ over some topological space $M$ and then have talking about the (topological) subbundle.  If it's not an embedding, then you just have two smooth vector bundles $E\to M$ and $D\to M$ that have some overlapping (set) characteristics.

Comment: @CL I think this would be similar to saying you have a smooth map $f:M\to N$ of smooth manifolds, and trying to say $T_pM\leq T_{f(p)}N$.  You can certainly make sense of the pushforward, but you don't consider $M$ a submanifold of $N$.  So why should you consider $D$ a subbundle of $E$?

Comment: I see, thanks a lot, I will think more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring that a subbundle be embedded determines its topological and smooth structure uniquely. In fact it is generally true that if $S\subseteq M$ then there is at most one topological and smooth structure with respect to which the inclusion is a smooth embedding. See Theorem 5.31 on page 114 of Lee's *Smooth Manifolds*.

The requirement is also natural for the reason pointed out by Matt. It allows us to think of the tangent space $T_pD$ of a subbundle as a subspace of the tangent space $T_pE$ of the bundle.

At the same time that embedding immediately gives us uniqueness of smooth structure on a subbundle (although Theorem 5.31 is actually fairly nontrivial), I also believe that uniqueness follows even without the embedding condition. Suppose $D\subseteq M$ has two different smooth structures under which it is a subbundle. These two smooth structures give two different local frames for $D$ in a neighborhood of any point. Composing with the differential of the smooth inclusion map, these smooth frames are also smooth in $M$. Then vector fields in either frame can be expressed as a smooth linear combination of vector fields in the other frame, meaning that the two smooth structures have to be the same.

I'm also fairly sure that any smooth (not necessarily embedded) subbundle must be embedded anyway. This would mean that the embedded condition is redundant, but it doesn't hurt and does make certain things clear from the get-go.